# An algorithm that could find a random cycle in a graph

Tags: routing, network, graph

I am looking for an algorithm that could find a random cycle in a graph from a node while that cycle is traversing around another nodes (area). For example, from the green star on the left of the image, finds a random cycle that goes around the red-star nodes.
[image]

Comment: Djikstras algorithm could be modified to close the path http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm, then out of the multitude of closed paths return the smallest that contains all the points.. are you coding this? if so what language?

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will be coding it in Java. Any recommendation?!

Comment: The algorithm is quite simple, start by making connections (junctions) then fan out recursively until you have a solution... it basically builds all the possible paths and then abandons those that don't meet criteria. I used length as I was looking for a shortest path but you'd be better off not abandoning until you have found closure and then deciding if it fulfills the requirement... is this in Esri or OGR geometry types? (they work fairly much the same) from start to closure build a polygon then decide if it contains all the points.